# Setting coordinates from openstreetmap as state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, openstreetmap

I'm trying to fetch coordinates from a specific city and set them as a state to use as a map provider.

I'm pretty sure it's something stupid, but I've spent more time on this than I want to admit.

It sorta works, I can set the state and I can console.log the coords, however, it's first null, null. Then lat, null, and at last, lat long. Like this.

```
null null
101.6942371 null
101.6942371 3.1516964
```

I want to set the last two coordinates as state and I think it works as it should, but, I want to use this state as lat and long, like this:

```
  latitude: lat,
 longitude: long,
```

When I do this, I get "Error: `longitude` must be supplied". I believe it's because it tries to set null, null as coordinates.

The code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MapGL, { GeolocateControl } from "react-map-gl";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from "leaflet-geosearch";

const Map = (props) => {
  const [long, setLong] = useState(null);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);

  const styles = {
    width: "100%",
    height: "85%",
    position: "absolute",
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const results = await provider.search({ query: props.currentCity });
      setLong(results[0].x);
      setLat(results[0].y);

    };

    console.log(long, lat)
    fetchData();
  }, [long, lat]);

  const TOKEN =
    "xxx";

  const [viewport, setViewPort] = useState({
    width: "75%",
    height: 400,
    latitude: lat,
    longitude: long,
    zoom: 12,
  });

  const _onViewportChange = (viewport) => {
    setViewPort({ ...viewport, transitionDuration: 3000 });
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "0 auto" }}>
      <MapGL
        {...viewport}
        style={styles}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        onViewportChange={_onViewportChange}
      ></MapGL>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

I'll just use the component as .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Gave up and went with a mix of mapboxgl and openstreetmapprovider.

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/

Pretty dumb I didn't do that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to fix the first 2 states of your "provider.search()" async function, this might work:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const results = await provider.search({ query: props.currentCity });
  if (results[0].x && results[0].y) {
    setLong(results[0].x);
    setLat(results[0].y);
    setViewPort({...viewport, 
                    latitude: results[0].y,
                    longitude: results[0].x,});
  }

};
```

Additionally you could do:

```
{viewport.latitude && viewport.longitude && <MapGL
    {...viewport}
    style={styles}
    mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN}
    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
    onViewportChange={_onViewportChange}
  ></MapGL>}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, nothing happens. The issue persists. But, I am curious, this looks much like what I already have, except for results[0]. What's the point of that, and what made you believe this might've worked? I'm quite new to this, so I'm trying to soak up knowledge. Cheers! :)

Comment: Trying to guess the flow as do not have a working example to troubleshoot... I think I have a better understanding, I have updated my answer which might be more accurate.

Comment: I think one your need to stop updating to "null" in anycase, and second your need to update your viewport, as I see it updated only when onViewportChange is triggered (only the viewport seem to contain your coordinates, but that's hard to clarify without having a working example), if doesn't work can you create a simpler JSFiddle?

Comment: Yes. I figured out that it's probably due to A, state being set to null, and that there's something weird with the viewport, as you say, it only updates when you play with the map. Let me set up a fiddle for you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: have updated the answer about the viewport issue, if first setup is failing, maybe the next renders are broken...?

Comment: Dang, I forgot that props comes from a context. So props.currentCity will never work unless it's called in its order. Changing that to a city name should suffice.